# Why do pictures uploaded with Facebook's Graph API (via AJAX POST) get the "Only Me" permission?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm generating a picture using HTML5 Canvas and posting it to a user's timeline using the `/me/photos` endpoint like this:

```
var canvas = self.canvas[0],
    // get a data url of the canvas contents, like data:image/png;base64,abcdefghijk
    dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'),
    // get the base64 data without the url portion, like abcdefghijk
    data = dataUrl.substring(dataUrl.indexOf(',') + 1),
    // get the raw binary data
    rawData = atob(data);

// create an array buffer of the raw data
var buffer = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);
for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i)
{
    buffer[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
}

// create a blob out of the array buffer, which we're going to send in the form data
var blob = new Blob([ buffer ], { type: 'image/png' })

// create the form data that we're going to send
var formData = new FormData();

//formData.append('access_token', response.authResponse.accessToken);
formData.append('source', blob);
formData.append('message', 'Test message');
formData.append('privacy', '{"value": "ALL_FRIENDS"}');

// send via ajax
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + response.authResponse.accessToken,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log('posted image', data, textStatus);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('failed to post image', textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

This works - somewhat. The picture is uploaded into an album created for the application. However, the picture is set to the "Only Me" permission, and it needs to be approved:

[image: Picture Approval]

How can I control this permission and get the picture to post directly to the user's timeline? Meaning, the picture needs to have the "Friends" permission and the user should not have to approve the picture in the album.

I've tried setting the `privacy` parameter to `ALL_FRIENDS` (see above code), but that doesn't appear to have any effect. Furthermore, when I authorize the application via the login dialog, I am not prompted for any sort of permission options.

So where is "Only Me" coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You can't post anything beyond the user's set permissions. So you must have your own account's permissions for photos set to "Must be approved". Check out https://www.facebook.com/help/www/385017548218624 to see how to change your permissions.

Comment: The privacy settings I see in the documentation to refer to audiences of individual albums. What happens if the app doesn't have an album yet, and the photo upload action is what creates the album? I always see apps posting photos on my friends' behalf, certainly my friends aren't individually approving each app's photos?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your app is not in sandbox mode? and what was the general privacy setting of your app when you authorized it? if you first authorized in "only me" mode, your privacy settings for each post won't have any effects

Comment: The app is in sandbox mode. Could that affect the privacy options? I'll try it without sandbox mode and report back. Regarding the initial privacy setting, I was not asked for a privacy setting when authorizing the app.

Comment: in privacy mode, you can only post in 'only me' privacy option